# MPMoviePlayerController endless loading (filepicker)

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to stream a video uploaded on filepicker, but it keeps loading without playing the video.

The link is: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/fLayj5bYTWuso1TVNknv

The page is a video/mp4 page, but as you can see there is no extension for the page.

The Code:

```
@interface RTVideo()
@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
@end

@implementation RTVideo
UIView *frame;
-(void)play
{
    NSNumber *adId = 5 ;
    NSString *session = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"sessionID"];
    NSString *type = @"video";
    [NetworkManagerCenter retrievePageWithtype:type
                                    Id:adId
                               session:session
                               success:^(RT *ad) {
                                   [self playAD];
                               } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                   [self removeFromSuperview];
                               }];
}

-(void)playAD
{
    frame = self;
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/fLayj5bYTWuso1TVNknv"];
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [frame addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    self.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
@end
```

Is this not working because there is no extension and how can I solve this?

Comment: Show more code / context. Show exactly where / when this code is running. Prove that `movieURL` is not nil, please.

Comment: Show how you know it is "loading".

Comment: the player is declared in a method that is called after the movieURL requested successfully from our servers. 

its not nil (using NSLog)

and it shows that it is loading from the player itself.

@matt

Comment: "the player is declared in a method that is called after the movieURL requested successfully from our servers" That is meaningless. The player is "declared" right here; if you declare it in two places, that's the problem. But that's not the point. Do not talk around the issue. I don't believe your words or even know what they mean. I said show more code. Show it.

Comment: So what is RTVideo? Is it a UIView subclass? Can you prove that it is even in the interface at the time this method is called? This is a very strange way to summon a movie player...